# AppSandboxing - Accessibility / AXUIElement

Tags: macos, appstore-approval, appstore-sandbox, accessibility-api

I thinking about sharing my first cocoa app with other people, and I really wanted it to be through Mac App Store.

My app is using Application Services (AXUIElements) and it is working fine while the sandbox is off - as soon as I turn it on a simple code to retrieve for example current window on focus is not working - I get nil as a result.

Is it possible to sandbox this kind of app or will I have to stick to using it alone (and maybe distribute using WWW site)?

Answer (score 0):

You may point users to System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibilty to your app. It will then be trusted and AX-API will work.

Comment: I forgot about this question. After contacting apple support they said I can't use any Accessibility API if I want to publish my app, so I ended up using it on my own.